# How to reduce hero banner webpart size in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, spfx

I tried to make SharePoint hero banner in SharePoint 365 but it takes unnecessary space and it looks really bad. So how can we reduce the SharePoint hero size?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The size is built-in and it's responsive, so it will dynamically resize for different devices and screen sizes. The "looks really bad" is subjective. The hero web part is designed to have big images that are easy to click or tap on any device. You may not like how it looks, but that is how it is served.

If you want to get serious about redesigning the SharePoint user experience you will need to get into the SharePoint Framework, which is a very deep developer vault.